# EFI VMWare Virtual SCSI Hard Drive (0.0)

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, vmware-workstation, osx-mavericks

I am trying to turn on Mavericks in VMware, but I get this error:

> EFI VMware Virtual SCSI Hard Drive (0.0)

And then it restarts, errors again, restarts, errors, restarts, etc.

I don't understand what the problem is. 
Can you tell me what to do please?

Comment: This is an old question that just got resurrected by the community bot.  I assume it has long been overtaken by events.  If so, there's no problem left to solve, and the problem is likely not reproducible.  If it's still an open issue, there isn't enough information here to determine a solution and the link is dead.  I'm going to vote to close.  If you would prefer to keep this open, please edit the question to provide details.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue. If you're on the same versions, you can fix this by reinstalling VMware 8.0.1 and then [download unlock-all-v102](http://www.mediafire.com/download/b171ssg801678j1/unlock-all-v102.zip) and use that to patch to support 10.7.2 on 8.0.1. That worked for me anyway.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I tried to reinstall it and to repatch it too but no result :/ I got vmware version 10.